# Icons overlap line items in landscape view

Tags: ios, iphone, icons, landscape, overlap

In a mobile app developed by a friend when you are in landscape mode on an iPhone there are icons that overlap text.

I wonder if this is a common problem and if it is obvious to anyone what possible factors could cause this?

See screenshots below:

Regular

### [image: Regular]

Landscape
[image: Landscape]

Answer (score 0):

There has to be an issue in the project with constraints. The text and the icons are not constrained to themselves so when the screen width changes their position changes as well. It looks like the icons are misplaced in the landscape view so I would start looking for the solution in that direction.

This is quite common and thankfully easy to fix mistake. New developers are working with fixed screen sizes and forget that there are multiple sizes to consider. Working with constraints will come along with experience so don't worry.